# Getting highest date from array of dates before 1970

Tags: javascript, function, sorting, date

Why isn't my code working? I thought once I used getTime() on the dates instead of trying to compare the dates it would work but it does not. Please help. Also I realize there is now way this example could be equal but for my actual project it can be so please don't exempt from any answers. Thank You.

```js
var x = new Date(1960,07,16);
var y = new Date(1950,04,28);
var z = new Date(1940,01,07);
    
var playerData = [
    {name: "John", date: x.getTime()},
    {name: "Bill", date: y.getTime()},
    {name: "Greg", date: z.getTime()},
    
];

function findHighScore() {
    var highDateSoFar = null;
    var result;
    for (var i = 0; i < playerData.length; i++) {
        if (playerData[i].date > highDateSoFar) {
            result = playerData[i];
            highDateSoFar = playerData[i].date;
        }
        else if (playerData[i].date === highDateSoFar) { 
            result = 'equal';
        
    }
    }
    return result;
}
    
var highPlayer = findHighScore();
var highPlayerName = highPlayer.name;
var highPlayerDate = highPlayer.date;
var highPlayerIndex = playerData.indexOf(highPlayer);
console.log({highPlayer});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem is that you are initialising `highDateSoFar` to `null`. When you do a greater than comparison to null you won't get the result you are looking for. Change the init to `var highDateSoFar = -Number.MAX_VALUE`. This starts it as the lowest possible value, so that the first comparison will definitely be true.

```js
var x = new Date(1960,07,16);
var y = new Date(1950,04,28);
var z = new Date(1940,01,07);
    
var playerData = [
    {name: "John", date: x.getTime()},
    {name: "Bill", date: y.getTime()},
    {name: "Greg", date: z.getTime()},
    
];

function findHighScore() {
    var highDateSoFar = -Number.MAX_VALUE;
    var result;
    for (var i = 0; i < playerData.length; i++) {
        if (playerData[i].date > highDateSoFar) {
            result = playerData[i];
            highDateSoFar = playerData[i].date;
        }
        else if (playerData[i].date === highDateSoFar) { 
            result = 'equal';
        
    }
    }
    return result;
}
    
var highPlayer = findHighScore();
var highPlayerName = highPlayer.name;
var highPlayerDate = highPlayer.date;
var highPlayerIndex = playerData.indexOf(highPlayer);
console.log({highPlayer});
```

Comment: Thank you, that works. Btw I forgot to include do you know how I can make it so if two or more of the dates are equal, it will return the objects of all the players that have equal dates?

Comment: Use an array. If the comparison is equal to the high value, push it to the array. If its larger create a new array with just that one in it.

Comment: "*This starts it as the lowest possible value*" except for `-Infinity`, which is also less to type. :-)

Comment: @RobG Thanks for the tip. Criously, any perf differences for using `Infinity`?